# Array nested proxy

Tags: c++, arrays, proxy

I have created an array, and my problem is in the operator square brackets "[]". The array is shared to reduce copying it every time, so when a write operation needs to take place a private copy of the array must be made before. When using the operator "[]", there is no way of knowing if the operation on the entry will be a read or write operation. For this purpose proxy is used, instead of returning a reference to the entry, a proxy is created with a reference to the array object and the required entry in the array.

The code for operator "[ ]":

```
inline typename BasicTypesArray< T >::BasicTypesArrayProxy BasicTypesArray< T >::operator[]( UnsignedInteger64bits entryIndex )
{
    return ( BasicTypesArrayProxy( *this, entryIndex ) );
}
```

The code for the proxy constructor:

```
    inline BasicTypesArray< T >::BasicTypesArrayProxy::BasicTypesArrayProxy( BasicTypesArray< T >& basicTypesArray, UnsignedInteger64bits entryIndex ) :
    m_basicTypesArrayObject( basicTypesArray ),
    m_entryIndex( entryIndex )
    {}
```

The problem is that when compiling this using g++ i get the following error:

In file included from BasicTypesArrayTest.cpp:4:0:
../Utilities/GeneralPurposeContainers/Array/BasicTypes/BasicTypesArray/BasicTypesArray.h: In instantiation of ‘Universe::GeneralPurposeContainers::BasicTypesArray::BasicTypesArrayProxy Universe::GeneralPurposeContainers::BasicTypesArray::operator [with T = int; Universe::UnsignedInteger64bits = long unsigned int]’:

BasicTypesArrayTest.cpp:31:13:   required from here
../Utilities/GeneralPurposeContainers/Array/BasicTypes/BasicTypesArray/BasicTypesArray.h:2311:64: error: no matching function for call to ‘Universe::GeneralPurposeContainers::BasicTypesArray::BasicTypesArrayProxy::BasicTypesArrayProxy(Universe::GeneralPurposeContainers::BasicTypesArray::BasicTypesArrayProxy)’

```
         return ( BasicTypesArrayProxy( *this, entryIndex ) );
```

Sorry for the long error message.

Why does the compiler tries to call the proxy constructor with proxy and not with the reference to the class it is nested within??

Comment: with the ``const specifier`` you can overload the ``operator[]`` for read or write.

Comment: Of course that if the object is const there is no need to copy, but i don't want to make copies when a read operation needs to take place on an object that is not const

Comment: I read a similar problem introduced by Herb Sutter before, [http://www.gotw.ca/publications/optimizations.htm]. Maybe you can take a look at this great article ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it ready run the constructor of your class `BasicTypesArrayProxy( *this, entryIndex )`. But for returning a value, it has to run the copy constructor to the calling code. 
You can try this test: Set the return type of `operator[]` to reference (which will cause a crash in real run), to see whether your code can pass the compile stage.

Comment: hai pham le, the link you gave does not work. Do you have any other information on the problem??

Comment: Please try http://www.gotw.ca/publications/optimizations.htm link again. It's a design for your problem. And about the constructor, if you set `operator[]` to return reference, could it pass the compile stage ?